# Authenticating users to and from different subdomain

Tags: sharepoint-server, authentication, forms-authentication, claims-based-auth

On SharePoint I can login using FBA. Now I want to be able to go to a different web application on a different subdomain and be authenticated on there as well without having to login again. It also needs to work the other way around.

Anyone who can help me with this?

Thanks in advance!